# DataTable Modifies Date Format - WHY?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, datatable

So I issue a test query like `SELECT *` from my table with a `start_date` column that has a `Date` data type. This query is then made into a DataTable, after which it's converted to a CSV file. In SSMS, the query returns only the date, as you can see here:

[image: SSMS Query]

But when I downloaded the converted CSV file, the dates came out like this:

[image: CSV file]

What I want to know is **why**. Why does the `DataTable` behave like this? I can't find a direct answer in the documentation of `DataTable`.

This is on the ASP.NET 4.0 C# platform with SQL Server 2008.

Thanks!

Comment: It is because of the conversion to string when exporting the data table to your csv file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataTable` uses .NET DateTime class and it probably get converted to string with `DateTime.ToString()` method when CSV is created. That method uses date format from current Thread's Culture settings. You need to use `DateTime.ToString(string format)` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when creating CSV to specify desired format of DateTime.

[Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) general description of culture-specific DateTime formatting on .NET platform.

Comment: Just a thought: Couldn't you explicitly state/cast that the column should be treated as _Date_ rather than _DateTime_ in the datatable?

Comment: @cyberj0g Can you link me to a documentation which explains the use of `DateTime` by `DataTable`? Thanks!

Comment: @Jeano Ermitaño Added link to the answer.

Comment: @Mackan No, there's no Date class in .NET base class library. Dates are represented by DateTime with time set to midnight.

Comment: True, but there is DateTime.Date :)

Comment: It's still DateTime so no difference.

Comment: I see. Basically .NET only has DateTime class, no Date, which is used by the DataTable. Binding Date values from SQL to the DataTable converts them to DateTime, thus adding the midnight time. Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a `DataTable` issue.

T-SQL [`date` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) mapped with [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) CLR data type. That means, even this type contains only date part in SQL Server, when you map this to `DateTime`, it's time part will be [midnight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight) *by default*.

Other than that, this `2015-06-17` and `6/17/2015 12:00:00 AM` values are just a different *textual* representation of this values. And *textual* representation depends on your current culture settings and/or CSV file settings etc..

Comment: So you're saying that, by default, the `Date` data type in SQL Server has `12:00:00 AM`, but is hidden when queried? I tried converting the dates to varchar(10) and it appeared correctly in the CSV as date only.

Comment: Not in SQL server @JeanoErmitaño. If you specify _date_, that's what it stores. It's adding the time portion in c#, defaulting to 00:00:00/12:00:00AM

Comment: @Mackan Therefore, the `Date` in SQL Server gets converted to `DateTime` (as stated by @cyberj0g), when I convert query results to a `DataTable`?

Comment: @JeanoErmitaño Yes in your second comment. Sql Server `Date` type mapped with .NET `DateTime` type. When you get it from your SQL Server in a DataTable, DataSet etc.. it will be mapped to  `DateTime` type. Since this keeps only date part, it's time part will be midnight by default. `Date` is saved as a binary in SQL Server as well.